# How to take a number out of a list and put on another list

Tags: python, list

I have some code that creates a list with numbers, from 1 to 561. I want to create a variable that is called "ultimate" that has 45 of those values, but, the ones that I put on that list, I want it to be removed from the cards_id list. How can I do that? This is the general code I have.

```
def cards_id(x):
    list = []
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        list.append(i)

    return list

cards_id(561)

import random

print (random.choice(cards_id(561)))

from random import shuffle

for i in range(0,45):
    print (random.choice(cards_id(561)))
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to iterate, append cards to a new list and remove cards from the original one (very inefficient).
You may just shuffle the original list and take the first 45 elements, while changing the original list to take the remaining ones.

```
cards = list(range(1,562)) 
random.shuffle(cards)
selected, cards = cards[:45], cards[45:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` :

```
import numpy as np

cards_id = np.arange(561) + 1
ultimate = np.random.choice(cards_id, 45)
cards_id = np.setdiff1d(cards_id, ultimate)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
def cards_id(x):
    lis = []
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        lis.append(i)
    return lis
import random
cards_id_list=cards_id(561)
ultimate=[]
for i in range(0,45):
    a=random.choice(cards_id_list)#random element from the list
    ultimate.append(a)
    cards_id_list.remove(a)#remove from the list here
```

Comment: Do I add that to the code, or do I substitute that for what I already have?

Comment: Not a good idea to use same name for function and variable. Also, don;t use `list` as the variable name

Comment: @curious You can see the whole code now and you can replace it with yours!

Comment: Small aside: You are working a little too hard to make `cards_id_list`.
`cards_id_list = list(range(1,562))` It's fine if you want it in a function but no need to iterate and append when you can just convert the range iterator to a list.

Comment: @ASaunders Yes i totally understand it, I just used it from the original code! Looks like the level of the programmer is beginner, hence it would be easier for him to understand it first this way.

Comment: Thank you all, it really helped! But what if I don't want to random choose 45 numbers, what if i make a list with 45 numbers and I want to take them out of the original list?